# How to query a value of a numrange field?

Tags: postgresql

I have a numrange field that as below:

```
A [0,100)
B [101,200)
```

How to query based on a value, ie. 110 -> it will returns B ..

I try:

```
select * From escalation_limit Where range_limit::numrange @>110::numrange
```

it returns:

> ```
> ERROR:  cannot cast type integer to numrange
> LINE 1: ... escalation_limit Where range_limit::numrange @>110::numrange
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [contains operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) `@>`:

```
select *
from the_table
where the_range_column @> 110::numeric;
```

Comment: ERROR:  operator does not exist: numrange @> integer
LINE 3: where range_limit @>110;

Comment: @DevDon: then cast it to numeric. But why do you use `numeric` if you just store integers? An `int4range` would be more appropriate - at least given your sample data .